# Sequence repeat validation using Regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Iam pretty new to regular expressions .I would like to prevent the user from entering in

String data using javascript function with  the following condition .

**Same sequence of characters cannot be repeated two or more times**

```
  aabhi - is allowed 
 aabbcc -  is allowed

 dayday - not allowed
 abab - not allowed
 ababab - not allowed 
 aaaa - not allowed
```

this applies to numbers too .Can someone help me with this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dayday not allowed but `aa` allowed?

Comment: well thats the requirement ;) since its 'sequence' and not characters that they have mentioned in condition , i guess that single character is allowed two times ..thanks for asking out ..

Comment: but `aaa` is not allowed which is single character?

Comment: am sorry ..Typo error .edited the question now aaaa not allowed

Comment: ok np, posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your inputs you can use this regex:

```
 /(\w{2,})(\1)/
```

**Code:**

```
re = /(\w{2,})(\1)/;

s = 'dayday';
if (re.test(s))
   console.log("invalid);
else
   console.log("valid);
```

Comment: It worked  ! you made my day:) .Being new , could you suggest me best place to know or have a trial with  regular expressions ?thanks once again

Comment: You're most welcome. Best reference for regex is: http://regular-expressions.info